# How to write header names based on value in columns using awk

Tags: awk

I have a tab delim input file with >100 columns with values ranging from 0-30. Below is a sample input file with 6 columns and 4 rows. First line is the header line.

```
ID      S1  S2  S3  S4  S5
CNV1    2   0   2   0   2
CNV2    6   2   2   2   1
CNV3    2   1   3   2   4
```

I would need to  create columns as 0,1,2,3,4 and >4 and fill in the columns with header names corresponding to the value of the column in the inputfile.   Sample output is shown below:

```
Output:
ID       0         1        2          3    4   >4
CNV1    S2,S4             S1,S3,S5
CNV2               S5     S2,S3,S4               S1
CNV3               S2     S1,S4        S3   S5
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{split($0,h); print $1,0,1,2,3,4,">4"; next}
                        {delete a; 
                         for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
                           {if($i>4)$i=4; 
                            a[$i]=(($i in a)?a[$i]","h[i]:h[i])} 
                           printf "%s\t",$1; 
                           for(i=0;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s\t", (a[i]?a[i]:" "); 
                           print ""}' file

ID      0       1       2       3       4       >4
CNV1    S2,S4           S1,S3,S5
CNV2            S5      S2,S3,S4                S1
CNV3            S2      S1,S4   S3      S5
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this version which is working with any number of values and headers:

```
awk '                     
FNR==1 {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {headers[i]=$i}}
FNR>1 {
  if (maxrow<FNR) { maxrow=FNR}
  rowheaders[FNR]=$1;
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
    if (maxvalue<$i) {maxvalue=$i}
    if(!values[$1,$i]) {
      values[$1,$i]=headers[i]
    } else {
      values[$1,$i]=values[$1,$i] "," headers[i]
    }
  }
}
END { for (i=2;i<=maxrow;i++) { for (j=0;j<=maxvalue;j++) { if (values[rowheaders[i],j] && maxlen<length(values[rowheaders[i],j])) { maxlen=length(values[rowheaders[i],j])}}} 
  printf("%" maxlen "s","ID"); for (i=0;i<=maxvalue;i++) { printf("%s%" maxlen  "s",OFS,i)}; printf("\n")
  for (i=2;i<=maxrow;i++) {
    printf ("%" maxlen "s",rowheaders[i])
    for (j=0;j<=maxvalue;j++) {
      if (!values[rowheaders[i],j]) {
        printf("%s%" maxlen "s",OFS," ")
      }
      else {
        printf("%s%" maxlen "s",OFS,values[rowheaders[i],j])
      }
    }
    printf("\n")
  }
}'
```

The test:

```
$ awk '                     
FNR==1 {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {headers[i]=$i}}
FNR>1 {
  if (maxrow<FNR) { maxrow=FNR}
  rowheaders[FNR]=$1;
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
    if (maxvalue<$i) {maxvalue=$i}
    if(!values[$1,$i]) {
      values[$1,$i]=headers[i]
    } else {
      values[$1,$i]=values[$1,$i] "," headers[i]
    }
  }
}
END { for (i=2;i<=maxrow;i++) { for (j=0;j<=maxvalue;j++) { if (values[rowheaders[i],j] && maxlen<length(values[rowheaders[i],j])) { maxlen=length(values[rowheaders[i],j])}}} 
  printf("%" maxlen "s","ID"); for (i=0;i<=maxvalue;i++) { printf("%s%" maxlen  "s",OFS,i)}; printf("\n")
  for (i=2;i<=maxrow;i++) {
    printf ("%" maxlen "s",rowheaders[i])
    for (j=0;j<=maxvalue;j++) {
      if (!values[rowheaders[i],j]) {
        printf("%s%" maxlen "s",OFS," ")
      }
      else {
        printf("%s%" maxlen "s",OFS,values[rowheaders[i],j])
      }
    }
    printf("\n")
  }
}' inputfile    

      ID        0        1        2        3        4        5        6
    CNV1    S2,S4          S1,S3,S5                                    
    CNV2                S5 S2,S3,S4                                  S1
    CNV3                S2    S1,S4       S3       S5
```